# looking for more explicit injection strict on form $f:\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I've seen some relevant posts on this question. I'm wondering if there are any methods to construct the injection $f:\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$ strictly on such domain and codomain without jumping back and forth claiming $\mathbb{Q}\sim\mathbb{N}\sim\mathbb{Z}$.

The general method I love is to rewrite the two rationals into decimals and then interleave the digit.

Here I want more explicit operation for rational cross rational to rational, any operation on this specific form $(\frac{p}{q},\frac{m}{n})$, where $\gcd(m,n)=\gcd(p,q)=1$ and $\frac{p}{q},\frac{m}{n}\in\mathbb{Q}$

Appreciate for any methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the many injections $\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q\to\Bbb Q$ is
$$f\left(\frac pq,\frac mn\right):=2^p3^q5^m7^n$$
where the two rationals are in canonical form, i.e. $p,m\in\Bbb Z,q,n\in\Bbb N,\gcd(p,q)=\gcd(m,n)=1$.